# Find, $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{4}\dotsm\cos\frac{x}{2^{n}} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

What's the answer is this limit and how is it solved?
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{4}\dotsm\cos\frac{x}{2^{n}}
$$

Comment: Is your $n^{th}$ term $\cos\frac{x}{n^2}$ or $\cos\frac{x}{2^n}$?

Comment: Why the absence of personal input, once again?

Comment: I up-voted this question (bringing its net score to 0) because I believe that a solution to this unique limit will give insight to current and future users and that its difficulty warrants anyone to request help evaluating it. Nevertheless, you should ideally include how your personal attempts to solve the problem have fared, even if that boils down to simply mentioning what methods have failed you, or give some context to what precipitated your post.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Multiply - divide by $$2\sin \frac x{2^n}$$

Edit:

Consider the product $$L=\prod_\limits{i=1}^n\cos\frac x{2^i}$$

Then $$L=\frac 12\frac{\sin\left(\dfrac x{2^n}\right)}{\sin\left(\dfrac x{2^n}\right)}\cos\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)\ldots\cos\left(\frac x2\right)$$

$$\Rightarrow L=\frac 1{\sin \left(\dfrac x{2^n}\right)}\frac 1{2^2}*2\sin\left(\frac x{2^{n-1}}\right)\cos \left(\frac x{2^{n-1}}\right)\ldots\cos\left(\frac x2\right)$$ and so on.

I hope this is enough to proceed further!

Comment: Shouldn't the coefficient be 2^n

Comment: Well, I was just trying to give you a head start. But yes, the final coefficient would be $2^n$

Comment: I dont how this hint gives the limit at the end of the day

Comment: The idea is to use that $\sin {2\theta}=2\sin\theta \cos\theta$

Answer (score 1):

### Check by induction that

or $$ \sin(x)=2\sin(\frac {x}{2^{}})\cos(\frac {x}{2^{}})=2^{2}\sin(\frac {x}{2^{2}})\cos(\frac {x}{2^{2}})\cos(\frac {x}{2^{}})\\\\ =2^{3}\sin(\frac {x}{2^{3}})\cos(\frac {x}{2^{3}}) \cos(\frac {x}{2^{2}})\cos(\frac {x}{2^{}}) =....=2^{n}\sin(\frac {x}{2^{n}})  \prod_{j=1}^n \cos(\frac {x}{2^{j}} x)$$

that is 
$$\sin(x)=2^{n}\sin(\frac {x}{2^{n}})  \prod_{j=1}^n \cos(\frac {x}{2^{j}} x) $$
So $$\prod_{j=1}^n \cos(\frac {x}{2^{j}} x)  = \frac{\sin x}{2^{n}\sin(\frac {x}{2^{n}}) } $$

Let set $h =\frac {x}{2^{n}}\to 0~~as~~n\to \infty $ then 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\prod_{j=1}^n \cos(\frac {x}{2^{j}} x)  = \lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{\sin x}{x } \frac{x}{2^{n}\sin(\frac {x}{2^{n}}) } \\=\frac{\sin x}{x } \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h}{\sin(h) } =\frac{\sin x}{x }$$

since $$ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(h) }{h}  = 1$$

Comment: I exactly reached here but don't know how to calculate the final limit

Comment: Ok have a look to the edit reload your page